# A tips for testing existence of subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I would ask you a tips. :)
I have two views which contains many subviews (in fact they are buttons)
And I have to test my UITapGestureRecognizer touches to disallow it when I touch a button.
My code works very well. But it's not really cool to rewrite all subviews to testing them.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        // Disallow tapRecognizer for btn touched
        return !(touch.view == _categoriesBtn || // DISALLOW CATEGORIES BOTTOM MENU AND ITS BUTTONS
                 touch.view == _categories1Btn ||
                 touch.view == _categories2Btn ||
                 touch.view == _categories3Btn ||
                 touch.view == _myMenuView || // DISALLOW RIGHT MENU AND ITS BUTTONS
                 touch.view == _myMenuView.menu1Btn ||
                 touch.view == _myMenuView.menu2Btn ||
                 touch.view == _myMenuView.menu3Btn ||
                 touch.view == _myMenuView.menu4Btn ||
                 touch.view == _myMenuView.menu5Btn ||
                 touch.view == _myMenuView.menu6Btn ||
                 touch.view == _myMenuView.menu7Btn);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Regards,
KL94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a pointer to a view containing all of the buttons, you can use this code to see if the tap is on a button in that view.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    UIView *sview; //This is the superview containing the buttons
    if([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]])
        return !([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && [touch.view isDescendentOfView:sview]);
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The previous response was a good way but your solution is more what I need, thx dude.

Comment: I agree, this answer is better :)

Answer (score 1):

How about defining a set:

```
NSSet *views=[NSSet setWithObjects:  _categoriesBtn,  _categories1Btn, /*list your views here*/ ,nil];
```

Then test like this

```
  if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        // Disallow tapRecognizer for btn touched
        return ![views containsObject:touch.view]
  }
```